# Installing RRDTool without root access

Tags: installation, root, redhat, rrdtool, configuration

I am trying to install rrdtool without root access on RHEL. Ive done this before on a diff machine where all i had to do was give a prefix in the configure file like : ./configure --prefix=/installdir

However on this machine it seems a lot of dependencies needed for rrdtool are not installed such as libxml2 for instance. So i got the dependencies and installed them to a custom path using the prefix thing while configuring them.

The problem now is that i do not know how to tell rrdtool where these dependencies are located! From searching online all i can find is yum install tutorials for dependencies.

From what i understand i can use the LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS variables to point to the dependencies?

So i am doing something like this

export LDFLAGS="-L/nethome/mch/gInstall/libxml2/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/nethome/mchgInstall/libxml2/include/libxml2/libxml"

However when i run rrdtools configure script it still cannot find the dependencies!

Could anyone tell me whats the best way to go about it?

Thanks

Comment: BTW i saw this tutorial, I hope someone else can make more sense out of it than me.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/rrdbuild

Answer (score 0):

So I'm still in the process of installing the billion dependencies...
But at least it found `libxml`

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/nethome/mch/gInstall/libxml2/lib" 
export CPPFLAGS="-I/nethome/mchgInstall/libxml2/include/libxml2"
```

I went through the `config.log` file to see what was going wrong and basically my path in the `CPPFLAGS` was not what it wanted, I fixed that and it found it.

So now I'm back to installing dependencies and then their dependencies it's like a never ending recursive process!

There should be an easier way to do this?

---

For the benefit of others, this is the exact variables that I set before running configure.

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/nethome/mchaudary3/gInstall/libxml2/lib -L/nethome/mchaudary3/gInstall/cairo/lib -L/nethome/mchaudary3/gInstall/glib/lib -L/nethome/mchaudary3/gInstall/pango/lib -lpangocairo-1.0"

export CPPFLAGS="-I/nethome/mchaudary3/gInstall/libxml2/include/libxml2/  -I/nethome/mchaudary3/gInstall/cairo/include/cairo -I/nethome/mchaudary3/gInstall/glib/include -I/nethome/mchaudary3/gInstall/pango/include/pango-1.0"

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/nethome/mchaudary3/gInstall/pango/lib/pkgconfig/:/nethome/mchaudary3/gInstall/glib/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Comment: Yeah, it involves having root or sudo access, like a sysadmin should.

Comment: "There should be an easier way"... nope. What you're doing is how life was before package managers.  If you ignore the package manager, this is what you get.  Theoretically you could extract the executables from the package and just use them, but it sounds like you have none of the libraries rrdtool needed.

Comment: I dont, and ive installed them all! and setting the appropriate variables to get it to work.

All but pangocairo work! and i cant figure out why not!!!!